# Evaluating combinations of variables in a table, produces inconsistent results

Tags: units

I am trying to evaluate a combination of pairs of variables and then print them in a table, at the beginning it evaluates totally fine, but when reaching the last rows something strange happens

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(* Data *)
g = Quantity[32.2, "Feet"/"Seconds"^2];
rho = Quantity[1.94, "SlugsMass"/"Feet"^3];
mu = Quantity[2.73*10^-5, "PoundsForce"*"Seconds"/"Feet"^2];
L = Quantity[368, "Feet"];
epsilon = Quantity[1.5*10^-4, "Feet"];
z = Quantity[170, "Feet"];

(*Function to Evaluate*)
hb = z + (34 Q^2)/(g*Pi^2*Diameter^4) + 
   Power[-1.8 Log10[
       Power[epsilon/(3.7 Diameter), 1.11] + (6.9 Pi*mu*Diameter)/(
        4 rho*Q)], -2]*(8 L*Q^2)/(g*Pi^2*Diameter^5);
Diameters = 
 Table[Quantity[x, 
   "Inches"], {x, {1, 1.25, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10}}]
Flows = Table[Quantity[x, "Gallons"/"Minutes"], {x, 200, 375, 25}];
Data = Table[hb, {Q, Flows}, {Diameter, Diameters}];
TableForm[Data, TableHeadings -> {Flows, Diameters}, 
 TableDirections -> Row]
```

[image]

All the results should be in ft, but as you can see in the image, some have different units, but I don't know why. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Please include the definition for 'Q'. What would be its units?

Comment: Q will be evaluated by substituting the Flow values. `Table[hb, {Q, Flows}, {Diameter, Diameters}];`

Comment: It seems that, towards the end, unit simplification is no longer carried out. You could try adding a `// UnitSimplify` at the end of your calculation of `Data`, but it will probably convert to SI units in the process. Try `UnitConvert[Data, "Feet"]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot I was so worried I didn't stop to think about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define as function as shown and use UnitConvert as @MarcoB suggested.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Data*)
g = Quantity[32.2, "Feet"/("Seconds"^2)];
rho = Quantity[1.94, "SlugsMass"/("Feet"^3)];
mu = Quantity[2.73*10^-5, "PoundsForce"*"Seconds"/("Feet"^2)];
L = Quantity[368, "Feet"];
epsilon = Quantity[1.5*10^-4, "Feet"];
z = Quantity[170, "Feet"];
Diameters = 
 Table[Quantity[x, 
   "Inches"], {x, {1, 1.25, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10}}]
(*Function to Evaluate*)
hb[Diameter_, Q_] := 
  z + (34 Q^2)/(g*Pi^2*Diameter^4) + 
   Power[-1.8 Log10[
       Power[epsilon/(3.7 Diameter), 
         1.11] + (6.9 Pi*mu*Diameter)/(4 rho*Q)], -2]*(8 L*Q^2)/(g*
       Pi^2*Diameter^5);

Flows = Table[Quantity[x, "Gallons"/"Minutes"], {x, 200, 375, 25}]
Data = Table[
   hb[Diameter, Q] // UnitConvert[#, "Feet"] &, {Q, Flows}, {Diameter,
     Diameters}];
TableForm[Data, TableHeadings -> {Flows, Diameters}, 
 TableDirections -> Row]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this `Data = Map[UnitConvert[#, "Feet"]&, Table[hb, {Q, Flows}, {Diameter, Diameters}]];`